# Removing event listener from custom element

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events, removeeventlistener

I have a problem removing event listener from a custom created element. The code below runs but I still get more event listeners (showed on screens below in chrome devtools).

```
stopPropagation(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      },

saveFileDocument() {
    
   let elementToDownload = document.createElement("a");
    // Some code to add attributes and stuff
   // like "download" (i'm not sure it this is relevant)

  document.body.appendChild(elementToDownload);

  

  elementToDownload.addEventListener("click", this.stopPropagation);
  elementToDownload.click();
  elementToDownload.removeEventListener("click", this.stopPropagation);

  document.body.removeChild(elementToDownload);
  elementToDownload = null;
}
```

Screen from devtools (before and after click):

[Before (549 listeners)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hnzR.png)

[After (551 listeners)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmhAO.png)

The funny thing: when I remove the line with removing event listener the listnener count only increases by 1 on each function call.
Frontend framework I work on is Vue but I don't think it's Vue related.

This is my first question so sorry if I didn't go in too many details. I can add them when requested.

Thanks,

Paweł

Comment: You trying to use native JS event, you should prefer synthetic VUE events: `<button v-on:click="yourHandlerFunction">btn</button>`

Comment: well implementation requires it to be handled this way. The real question is why those event listeners stay there even thou I'm removing this listener in same function that creates it?